# some weird result of pthread program

Tags: c, pthreads

It is a very simple multithread program. It will create two threads and run.

In the thread, it will copy the `argv0` to `origname`.

At the first time, the `origname` is correct.

But after entering into the while loop, the origname will be corrupted by the `sprintf`.

It will print like:

`Hello World! It's me, thread #0 ./multithread 3!`

`origname 0 ./multithread 3!`

the content of `origname` is the parameter for the `sprintf`. I don't understand what is the reason. Anyone can help?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     2
void sendstring(char *string)
{
    printf("%s",string);
}
struct thread_data{
    int  thread_id;
    char *argv0;
};

struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_THREADS];


void *PrintHello(void *parameter)
{
    struct thread_data *childpara;
    childpara = (struct thread_data *)parameter;
    int i = 0;
    char origname[20];
    strncpy(origname, childpara->argv0,strlen(childpara->argv0));
    origname[strlen(childpara->argv0)] = '\0';
    printf("init origname %s argv0 %s\n",origname, childpara->argv0);

    while(1)
    {
            printf("origname %s\n",origname);
            sleep(1);
            char buffer[30];
            sprintf(buffer,"Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld %s %d!\n", childpara->thread_id, childpara->argv0, i++);
            sendstring(buffer);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;
    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
            thread_data_array[t].thread_id = t;
            thread_data_array[t].argv0 = argv[0];
            rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello,(void *) &thread_data_array[t]);      

            if (rc){
                    printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
                    exit(-1);
            }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a buffer overrun.  I count:

```
Hello World! It's me, thread #0 ./multithread 3!
```

at over 40 characters, but you are sprintf'ing it into a 30 byte buffer.  After this has happened, all bets are off.  The result is undefined.  It could crash, it could do weird things, it could make a nanobot and send it out to buy coffee for the entire dev team.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coming from this line:

```
thread_data_array[t].argv0 = argv[0];
```

argv is defined as `char **argv` (same as `char *argv[]`), thus argv[0] is a pointer. As a result, `thread_data_array[t].argv0` is an alias of the data in `argv`.

In the end, the two threads share the same string, and everything gets messed up. Don't ask me for the exact details of what gets screwed up when, because there are a large number of things that can happen when you do this, depending on which line of code runs when.

You need to use [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) instead. This way, each thread has its own copy, and the two threads to not mess with one another.

Comment: This is what I want. I want to use the argv[0] as the parameter to the new created thread. I think this is not the problem. I copy the content from this pointer to the origname, but not the pointer. When I comment the sprintf, it works correctly.

Comment: You need to understand--you are *not* copying the content. You are merely copying the pointer, meaning that both threads point to the same memory space. Use strcpy().

Comment: In addition, there is no sort of semaphore/barrier/mutex on the output, so when you do get it running, the output of the two threads will occasionally be scrambled.

Comment: I have found the problem. It is because that the buffer[30] is too small. The content has exceeded its size and it will be written into the array of origname on the same stack. BTW, thank you all the same.

Comment: @Zhongshu, glad you found the answer. Best of luck.